# DataTables warning: table id=Table4 - Incorrect column count - Where is the issue?

Tags: html

I have created the above table and it throws me an error msg when I try and load it about **Incorrect column count**:

```
<table id="Table4" class="table table-bordered table-striped">

<thead>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="14" style="text-align:center;line-height: 10px;  background-color:#0D5061;color:white"> <b>INFO</b></th>
    </tr> 
    <tr style="background-color:#DDDDDD;">
        <th colspan="5" style="text-align:center;">Title1</th>
        <th colspan="5" style="text-align:center;">Title2</th>
        <th colspan="1" style="text-align:center;">Title3</th>
        <th colspan="1" style="text-align:center;">Title4</th>
        <th colspan="1" style="text-align:center;">Title5</th>
        <th colspan="1" style="text-align:center;">Title6</th>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color:#DDDDDD;">
        <th colspan="1" style="text-align:center; font-size: 13px;">SubTitle1</th>
        <th colspan="1" style="text-align:center; font-size: 11px;">SubTitle2</th>
        <th colspan="1" style="text-align:center; font-size: 12px;">SubTitle3</th>
        <th colspan="2" style="text-align:center; font-size: 12px;">SubTitle4</th>
        <th colspan="1" style="text-align:center; font-size: 13px;">SubTitle5</th>
        <th colspan="1" style="text-align:center; font-size: 11px;">SubTitle6</th>
        <th colspan="1" style="text-align:center; font-size: 12px;">SubTitle7</th>
        <th colspan="2" style="text-align:center; font-size: 12px;">SubTitle8</th>
        <th colspan="1" style="text-align:center; font-size: 12px;">SubTitle9</th>
        <th colspan="1" style="text-align:center; font-size: 12px;">SubTitle10</th>
        <th colspan="1" style="text-align:center; font-size: 12px;">SubTitle11</th>
        <th colspan="1" style="text-align:center; font-size: 12px;">SubTitle2</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="1" style="text-align:center; font-size: 13px;">1</td>
        <td colspan="1" style="text-align:center; font-size: 11px;">2</td>
        <td colspan="1" style="text-align:center; font-size: 12px;">3</td>
        <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center; font-size: 12px;">4</td>
        <td colspan="1" style="text-align:center; font-size: 13px;">5</td>
        <td colspan="1" style="text-align:center; font-size: 11px;">6</td>
        <td colspan="1" style="text-align:center; font-size: 12px;">7</td>
        <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center; font-size: 12px;">8</td>
        <td colspan="1" style="text-align:center; font-size: 12px;">9</td>
        <td colspan="1" style="text-align:center; font-size: 12px;">10</td>
        <td colspan="1" style="text-align:center; font-size: 12px;">11</td>
        <td colspan="1" style="text-align:center; font-size: 12px;">12</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>

</table>
```

What is wrong with my table structure and it throws me this message ? My columns seems to be equal to each other... All Colspan are 14 for each line or Header.

Comment: It seems like colspan use is supported in thead, but not in tbody. So, that might be the reason for the warning.